# Django nested serializer instance update issue

Tags: python, django, django-models, backend, django-serializer

I am building a django backend rest API and I have an issue which I can't overcome. So I have two models.

#1 Company Model:

```py
class Company(models.Model):
    companyID = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

#2 Employee Model:

```py
class Employee(models.Model):
    employeeID = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    companyID = models.ForeignKey(Company, db_column="companyID", related_name='employees', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I would like to create a serializer which is get one object like this (from PUT request):

```
{
  "companyID": 3,
  "name": "New Name",
  "employees": [
    {
      "employeeID": 31,
      "email": "goreca7783@fulwark.com",
    }
  ]
}
```

and it should update all of the values in the database.

Here's my serializer this is how I tried to solve this problem which is almost works.

```py
class CompanyEmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Serialize the employees of a company
    employees = EmployeeCompanySerializer(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ['companyID', 'name', 'employees']
    
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        employees_data = validated_data.pop('employees')
        company = Company.objects.create(**validated_data)
        
        for employee_data in employees_data:
            Employee.objects.create(companyID=company, **employee_data)
        
        return company
    
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        employees_data = validated_data.pop('employees')
        
        print("================VALIDATED_DATA=====================")
        print(validated_data.get('name', instance[0].name))
        # Update the company informations
        instance[0].name = validated_data.get('name', instance[0].name)
        print("================BEFORE_SAVE=====================")
        print(instance[0].name)
        instance[0].save()
        print("=================AFTER_SAVE====================")
        print(instance[0].name)
        
        # Update the employees
        # ...

        return instance[0]
```

Almost eveything works except one code block:

```py
instance[0].name= validated_data.get('name', instance[0].name)
```

For some reason it does not update **name** field or any kind of field in the Company Model. *Updating employees data is working*. This was printed in the **terminal**:

```
================VALIDATED_DATA=================
New Name
================BEFORE_SAVE====================
Test2 Company
=================AFTER_SAVE====================
Test2 Company
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: you code not have error in `instance[0]`? I think Instance mean have only one object of Company

Comment: The instace rerturns a query set which is actually an array so I needed to put the zero index there. A little bit wierd for me that but I don't know how to solve that issue. Maybe it would solve the update issue... @NgocPham

Comment: i think you can try query instance[0].id again. And update it. Like `Company.objects.filter(id= instance[0].id).update(name=name)`

Comment: But check again in `validated_data.get('name', instance[0].name)` That code mean if not found `name` in validated_data. It get instance[0].name for default data.